# Доступ к this из прототипа по таймеру

Tags: javascript

Как сделать, что бы в функции animate self ссылался на экземпляр Animation, а не на window, не прибегая к клонированию функции внутри Animation?

```
   var Animation = function (frameCount_) {
        var self = this;
        this.image = image_;
        this.frameCount = frameCount_;
        this.i = 1;
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
        this.animateTimer = 0;
        this.start();
    }
    Animation.prototype.start = function () {
        clearInterval(this.animateTimer);
        setInterval(this.animate, 50);
    }
    Animation.prototype.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(this.animateTimer);
    }
    Animation.prototype.animate = function () {
        if (self.i < self.frameCount) {
            self.i++;
        } else {
            self.i = 1;
        }
        self.x = (self.i - 1) * 50;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. не `Animation.this`, а `Animation.prototype`
2. `self` = `this` во второй строке не имеет смысла
3. в функции `animate self` не инициализировано, пологаю здесь должен быть `this`

По вопросу:

```
Animation.prototype.start = function () {
    var me = this;
    clearInterval(me.animateTimer);
    me.animateTimer = setInterval(function(){me.animate()}, 50);
}

Animation.prototype.stop = function () {
    clearInterval(this.animateTimer);
    this.animateTimer = null;
}
```

Comment: Да, простите, там был прототип, при копировании забыл исправить.
Смысл второй строки, если бы у меня функция animate была сразу внутри конструктора, то замыканием она была бы доступна при вызове этой функции по таймеру. Если бы контекст выполнения прототипа был внутри объекта, то переменная self для функции animate была бы проинициализорованна. Если же использовать this в animate, то оно ссылается на window

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего все-таки это не `self` а `this`, но можно наверное так:

```
Animation.this.animate = function () {
    if (this.i < self.frameCount) {
        this.i++;
    } else {
        this.i = 1;
    }
    this.x = (this.i - 1) * 50;
};
Animation.this.start = function () {
    clearInterval(this.animateTimer);
    with (this) {
        // setInterval(animate, 50); // тут была ошибка
        // Строчка ниже работает правильно
        animateTimer = setInterval(function () { animate(); }, 50); 
    }
};
```

Но я-бы переписал все это дело в виде класса

**UPDATE** - Исправил версию, при прямом использовании функции (без обертки) контекст теряется

Comment: И что, реально работает?

Comment: Чуть по-другому, но работает: http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/KRpUq/1/ ответ исправил

Comment: Ну, принципиально иначе